# Ruby Shoes: counting the amount of times a value occurs in an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing, duplicates, shoes

I'm making a Yahtzee game in Ruby using Shoes
when I click Button "Two" the code is suppose to count the amount of times the 
value 2 occurs in an array. For every instance of the value 2 that appears,
the score is incremented by 2.

This code works for a select amount of cases but on other cases like
@array = [2,1,2,2,3] # there are three 2's in the array so 
the score is suppose to be 6, but instead my code returns 4... why?

```
button "      twos     " do     
    @array.each_with_index do |value, index|
        if (@array[index] == 2)
            @score = @score + 2
            @points = @score + 2
        end #if     
end #loop end #button
```

Comment: What means that dollar signs?

Comment: Oh I'm a new user to this site, that was just a formatting error

Answer (score 6):

This code looking better, but, in fact, it does the same thing. Maybe you should check initial values of instance variables `@score` and `@points`?

```
@array = [2,1,2,2,3]

@score = @points = 0

@score = @array.count(2) * 2
@points = @score

@score
 => 6 
@points
 => 6
```

Comment: so I tried this code, when I got to @array = [2,4,2,2,4] it gave me a score of 2- why might this be?

Comment: If you try this code in the clean environment, irb, for example, it returns you 6. So I think the problem in the part of code that you didn't show. PS. now code looking even better)

Comment: hmm other than printing out the score using title, all the code I used in relation to @score is the same as yours, and when I print out the array it prints out the correct array. Thank you for your help though! it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it might help if you make lightweight version of your program, including only code needed to calculate and print out score, and then check how it will work.

Comment: Are you certain that the objects are equal? I mean might some of the 2s be "2"s? Please go through all of your elements and check ifputs "#{@array[index]}: #{@array[index] == 2}"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method. By means of **inject** you can implement abstract method for counting numbers and use it everywhere in your project:

```
def count_of_element array, element
  array.inject(0) { |count, e| count += 1 if e == element; count }
end

puts count_of_element [2,1,2,2,3], 2 # => 3
```

There could be even better solution – define method for Array class like this:

```
class Array
  def count_of_element element
    inject(0) { |count, e| count += 1 if e == element; count }
  end
end

puts [2,1,2,2,3].count_of_element 2 # => 3
```

It looks even cooler. Good luck!

Comment: Eeh, as you could see from Flexoid's solution, the `count` method exists already. No need to define your own.